# Code/Branch Coverage tool for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: nunit, code-coverage, visual-studio-2015, xunit.net, opencover

I'm looking for way to get code coverage in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. I wasn't able to find a free tool for VS2013, so wondering if anything new has happened in VS2015.

I'm currently using OpenCover but that doesn't color my code like so. Or I wasn't able to figure it out.

[image]

If no free tool is available what is the best paid tool then? Any that are free for open source projects?

Comment: Is $250 a big price for you budget? You can try SemanticDesigns. It is doing what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a visual studio extension called [OpenCover.UI](https://github.com/OpenCoverUI/OpenCover.UI) that uses [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/OpenCover) and is available in the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688)

Comment: Wonder why google didn't find this one, it's exactly what I need :) Thanks

Comment: It's quite new(ish) - slowly gaining momentum.